# How can I add new post to top of recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Where and what should I add in my code? I searched many answers but couldn't find the exact place to add in my code. Help me out

```
private void startPosting() {
        mProgress.setMessage("Posting to Blog....");

    final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    final String desc_val = mPostdesc.getText().toString().trim();
    final String date_val=txtDate.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && mImageUri != null) {

        mProgress.show();

        StorageReference filepath =mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

       filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

               @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

               DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
               newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
               newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
               newPost.child("Date").setValue(date_val);
               newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());

               mProgress.dismiss();

               startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

           }
```

Comment: Your question does not seem to be clear to me. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask helps you in improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems,
You are using Firebase database in your app! and want to add new post to the top of all. Practically Firebase will push new node at last position.

So, 
What you can do is, insert the time of post along with all the info, and query the database to get ordered list by time, using `orderBy("child")`.

Now, 
You just need to reorder this list by `DESC` order by client side, or use [setStackFromEnd(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setStackFromEnd(boolean)) method on `recyclerview`

Comment: newPost.child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
How can i add negative timestamp value to make order in descending order?

Comment: You doesn't have to use negative timestamp. Instead `setStackFromEnd(boolean)` will do the trick for you.